# Is it possible to override default "_id" index and make it compound?

Tags: c#, mongodb, .net-core, mongodb-.net-driver

I would like to use Mongo's ObjectId, but I would need this value not to be unique; instead of what my unique PK would be composed by this ObjectId + a creation date.
Kind of composite key that I would like:

```
// Same key, only date changes. The composition of Key + CreatedAt stays unique
_id: {Key:"5df7688f4bc75a55b0c4e16b", CreatedAt:"2019-12-11T11:20:47.678+00:00"}
_id: {Key:"5df7688f4bc75a55b0c4e16b", CreatedAt:"2019-12-16T11:20:47.678+00:00"}
_id: {Key:"5df7688f4bc75a55b0c4e16b", CreatedAt:"2019-12-18T11:20:47.678+00:00"}
```

One solution is to create a class type for strong typing of `Id` field in C# code:

```
public class ComposedKey
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
}

public class MyItemType
{
    // Mapped on Mongo's "_id"
    public ComposedKey Id { get; set; }
}
```

That works! But I would like the 2 fields `Key` and `CreatedAt` to be declared directly in `MyItemType` class, without using a sub class:

```
public class MyItemType
{
    // I want "_id" to map the following 2 fields
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }

    // Other fields ....
    public string Lastname { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

As official doc says:

> You cannot drop this index on the _id field.

So how could it be overriden to match my need?

What I managed to do so far: I could create a compound id based on `_id` and `createdAt` fields:

```cs
    var indexKeys = Builders<MyItemType>.IndexKeys.Combine(
                    Builders<MyItemType>.IndexKeys.Ascending(f => f.Id), 
                    Builders<MyItemType>.IndexKeys.Ascending(f => f.CreatedAt));
    var indexOptions = new CreateIndexOptions() { Unique = true };
    var createIndexModel = new CreateIndexModel<MyItemType>(indexKeys, indexOptions);
    await collection.Indexes.CreateOneAsync(createIndexModel);
```

But it does create a 2nd index and keeps the default unique index on `_id`... so that an ObjectId value cannot be duplicated. Moreover I would like to have only 1 index on my collection.

Comment: As you mentioned, Index on _id can't be deleted So you can not override _id index. Documentation says : https://api.mongodb.com/wiki/current/Indexes.html#Indexes-The%5CidIndex

Comment: Thanks @prasad_ that's what I've deduced also. As you can see I succeeded to map `_id` on a class type with more than one field, but I dont know how to map it on a set of fields of a class.